lvextend not using free space?
Im trying to increase the size of my pv/vg/lv after adding new storage enclosure and I created 2 new volumes and attached the to the host.
While increasing PV and VG worked very well it seems that LV does not see any free space.
Maybe someone can point me in the right direction why this is not working?
What was done so far:
rescan-scsi-bus.sh -r

pvcreate /dev/mapper/mpathe
  Physical volume "/dev/mapper/mpathe" successfully created.
pvcreate /dev/mapper/mpathf
  Physical volume "/dev/mapper/mpathf" successfully created.
vgextend vgall /dev/mapper/mpathe
  Volume group "vgall" successfully extended
vgextend vgall /dev/mapper/mpathf
  Volume group "vgall" successfully extended

but now lvextend shows this:
lvextend -l +100%FREE /dev/vgall/lvol0
  Using stripesize of last segment 4.00 KiB
  Rounding size (152285551 extents) down to stripe boundary size for segment (152285548 extents)
  Size of logical volume vgall/lvol0 changed from 478.39 TiB (125408168 extents) to 478.51 TiB (125439052 extents).
  Logical volume vgall/lvol0 successfully resized.

which is basically nothing, and subsequent runs do show:
lvextend -l +100%FREE  /dev/vgall/lvol0
  Using stripesize of last segment 4.00 KiB
  Rounding size (152285551 extents) down to stripe boundary size for segment (152285548 extents)
  Size of logical volume vgall/lvol0 unchanged from 478.51 TiB (125439052 extents).
  Command failed with status code 5.

Output of PV / LV / VG display below:
  --- Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/mapper/mpatha
  VG Name               vgall
  PV Size               <119.60 TiB / not usable 4.00 MiB
  Allocatable           yes (but full)
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              31352042
  Free PE               0
  Allocated PE          31352042

  --- Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/mapper/mpathb
  VG Name               vgall
  PV Size               <119.63 TiB / not usable 4.00 MiB
  Allocatable           yes (but full)
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              31359763
  Free PE               0
  Allocated PE          31359763

  --- Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/mapper/mpathc
  VG Name               vgall
  PV Size               <119.60 TiB / not usable 4.00 MiB
  Allocatable           yes (but full)
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              31352042
  Free PE               0
  Allocated PE          31352042

  --- Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/mapper/mpathd
  VG Name               vgall
  PV Size               <119.63 TiB / not usable 4.00 MiB
  Allocatable           yes (but full)
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              31359763
  Free PE               0
  Allocated PE          31359763

  --- Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/mapper/mpathe
  VG Name               vgall
  PV Size               <51.27 TiB / not usable 4.00 MiB
  Allocatable           yes
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              13438976
  Free PE               13431255
  Allocated PE          7721

  --- Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/mapper/mpathf
  VG Name               vgall
  PV Size               51.20 TiB / not usable 4.00 MiB
  Allocatable           yes
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              13422965
  Free PE               13415244
  Allocated PE          7721


  --- Volume group ---
  VG Name               vgall
  System ID
  Format                lvm2
  Metadata Areas        6
  Metadata Sequence No  5
  VG Access             read/write
  VG Status             resizable
  MAX LV                0
  Cur LV                1
  Open LV               1
  Max PV                0
  Cur PV                6
  Act PV                6
  VG Size               580.92 TiB
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              152285551
  Alloc PE / Size       125439052 / 478.51 TiB
  Free  PE / Size       26846499 / 102.41 TiB


  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/vgall/lvol0
  LV Name                lvol0
  VG Name                vgall
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Status              available
  # open                 1
  LV Size                478.51 TiB
  Current LE             125439052
  Segments               2
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           252:6



lvdisplay -m /dev/vgall/lvol0
  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/vgall/lvol0
  LV Name                lvol0
  VG Name                vgall
  LV UUID                MKcUYB-dAoJ-qJq1-hQEy-ArGl-c0bi-WKY0bU
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time localhost.localdomain, 2023-10-04 20:00:04 +0200
  LV Status              available
  # open                 1
  LV Size                478.51 TiB
  Current LE             125439052
  Segments               2
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           252:6

  --- Segments ---
  Logical extents 0 to 125408167:
    Type                striped
    Stripes             4
    Stripe size         4.00 KiB
    Stripe 0:
      Physical volume   /dev/mapper/mpathb
      Physical extents  0 to 31352041
    Stripe 1:
      Physical volume   /dev/mapper/mpathd
      Physical extents  0 to 31352041
    Stripe 2:
      Physical volume   /dev/mapper/mpatha
      Physical extents  0 to 31352041
    Stripe 3:
      Physical volume   /dev/mapper/mpathc
      Physical extents  0 to 31352041

  Logical extents 125408168 to 125439051:
    Type                striped
    Stripes             4
    Stripe size         4.00 KiB
    Stripe 0:
      Physical volume   /dev/mapper/mpathe
      Physical extents  0 to 7720
    Stripe 1:
      Physical volume   /dev/mapper/mpathf
      Physical extents  0 to 7720
    Stripe 2:
      Physical volume   /dev/mapper/mpathb
      Physical extents  31352042 to 31359762
    Stripe 3:
      Physical volume   /dev/mapper/mpathd
      Physical extents  31352042 to 31359762




The Lv was created as "striped" spanned over 4 PVs, so in otrder to extend it you need 4 PVs with free exttents. At the moment you have only 2, the others are full.

Ah yes, thanks for pointing me in the right direction.
The LV was initially created with 4 PV's simultaneously, and after adding only 2 new PV's i had to run:
lvextend -l+100%FREE /dev/vgall/lvol0 --stripes 2


From the man page it should be used as lvextend -l+100%FREE vgall/lvol0 with optionally -r to increase the FS at the same time.
For me it works on Fedora40 :
lvextend -l+100%FREE home_vg/New_home -r 
Size of logical volume home_vg/New_home changed from 465,70 GiB (119220 extents) to 465,74 GiB (119230 extents).

I just tried your command but its the same output as before (unchanged, status code 5) (lvextend -l+100%FREE /dev/vgall/lvol0 -r).
and btw i'm on a Fedora like Oracle Linux Server 9.2 with LVM TOOLS 2.03.17(2)

please post the output of:
lvdisplay -m /dev/vgall/lvol0

if segments type is "striped" and not "linear" you need to add a 3rd new disk in order to extend the LV.

updated my answer so it includes lvdisplay -m! I noticed in the command history that there was indeed 1 successful resize which basically did not increase the space available but also included that one for completeness

The Lv was created as "striped" spanned over 4 PVs, so in otrder to extend it you need 4 PVs with free exttents. At the moment you have only 2, the others are full.
